# LINQ query result in int type variable

Tags: linq, casting

I want the the LINQ query result in int type variable.

i have a query this will always return the single int value. i want result sumthing like that.

```
 int interlineId = from cSInterline in codeShareInterline_.AsEnumerable() 
                   where cSInterline.Field<int>("InterCodeId") == interCodeId[0] 
                   select cSInterline.Field<int>("PermitedPercent");
```

But it returning the error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int interlineId = (from cSInterline in codeShareInterline_.AsEnumerable() 
              where cSInterline.Field<int>("InterCodeId") == interCodeId[0] 
              select cSInterline).Single().Field<int>("InterCodeId");
```

Answer (score 6):

Your query is returning an `IEnumerable<int>`, with only one item in this case. So add `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` onto the end to return only that 1 item. If your query might return more than 1 item then use `FirstOrDefault`.

```
int interlineId = 
       (from cSInterline in codeShareInterline_.AsEnumerable() 
        where cSInterline.Field<int>("InterCodeId") == interCodeId[0] 
        select cSInterline.Field<int>("PermitedPercent")).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it should work):

```
 int? interlineId = (from cSInterline in codeShareInterline_.AsEnumerable() 
                   where cSInterline.Field<int>("InterCodeId") == interCodeId[0] 
                   select cSInterline.Field<int>("PermitedPercent")).FirstOrDefault();
```